# is it safe to delete x-cart cache files?

Tags: caching, x-cart

I am using an xcart eshop. The site is working fine but it has created more than 5 GB of data in tha datacahce folder. My question is: Is it safe to simply delete all these files as well as the file structure under the folder datacache in order to remove these 5GB of my server and how can I avoid future large caching. I also attach an indicative screenshot of the datacache filestructure.     [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `var/datacache` and `var/packs` sub-folders in your `X-Cart` installation.

I would also recommend you to set up a `cron` job to regularly clean up the content of the `var/datacache` folder.

For example:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com; find ./var/datacache -mmin +60 | xargs rm -rf
```

This command is aimed to find and remove all the files that are older than 60 minutes and located in the respective `var/datacache` sub-folder of your `X-Cart` installation.

Set up your `cron` job to be executed once per hour, via your website Control Panel (cPanel or Plesk).